# Replacing quotation marks in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

In excel file, I've 100s of dimension values like in feet & inches but include quotation marks. I'm trying to use SUBSTITUTE formula for this but it doesnt work with Excel 2016. It is giving me syntax error

- 10'x40'
- 100"x200"
- 50"x5"

I wish to convert those as:

- 10Feetx40Feet
- 100Inchx200Inch
- 50Inchx5Inch

(
Or preferably:

- 10x40Feet
- 100x200Inch
- 50x5Inch
  )

I've tried formulas -

1. =SUBSTITUTE(B1,CHAR(34),"")
2. =SUBSTITUTE(B1,"""","Inch")

But both times i get the error - 
[image]

Comment: the formula works for me, are you sure you are supposed to use `,` as the delimiter and not `;`

Comment: Bingo! My list-separator was changed to | in control panel. I reverted it and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these formulas, ou join them in one.

[=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B3;CONCATENATE(CHAR(39);"x");"x");CHAR(39);"Feet")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG7Zm.png)

PS: The answer would look better with the image... Please click on the link to view it. (edit)

Answer (score 0):

Substitute works based on your list separator settings. 
If you list separator is changed, this doesn't work with comma (,) it needs the separator specified there.

To find your list separator setting go to -

1. Make sure Excel is closed Navigate to control panel
2. Select ‘Region and Language’
3. Click the ‘Additional Settings’ button
4. Find the List separator and change it to a comma (,)

Answer (score 0):

With data in **A1**, in another cell enter:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,CHAR(39),"Feet"),CHAR(34),"inches")
```

and copy downward if necessary:

[image]